# How to update Label instead overwrite?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm stuck with a little `SpriteKit` game and got this inside my `projectileHit` function, and instead of updating the `label` to the current number of `monstersDestroyed`, it just overwrites it, so first a 1, then a 2 on top of the one, then a 3 and so on.

How do I make it "delete" the previous number first and then fill in the next one?

```
func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile:SKSpriteNode, monster:SKSpriteNode) {
    print("Hit")
    projectile.removeFromParent()
    monster.removeFromParent()
    monstersDestroyed++
    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")
    self.addChild(myLabel)
    myLabel.text = String(monstersDestroyed)
```

Comment: You are adding a label to the view every time in your function instead of updating an already implemented label - also why do you have 2 lines of `myLabel.text = String(monstersDestroyed)`

Comment: @zappiDev yes I deleted the second one already. But I don't know where to put the let myLabel with fontSize etc. else, if not inside the function. If I put it in the GameScene class it gives errors as well (declaration).

Comment: Try changing the `removeFromParent()` too `monster.removeFromSuperview()`

Comment: @zappiDev never mind found it, I put the let my label.. in the game scene class, the font size etc. in the function above, the addChild of the label in the didmovetoview function. No it updates correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move label outside the function, so it is created only once, and only change label text when collision happened.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
   var monstersDestroyed = 0
   let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")

   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
       self.addChild(myLabel)
   }

   func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile:SKSpriteNode, monster:SKSpriteNode) {
       monstersDestroyed++
       myLabel.text = String(monstersDestroyed)
   }
}
```